# Why application built with Ionic Framework substitute another Ionic app while installation on Android device

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework

I developed a few apps with Ionic framework (Angular).
When I build an .apk file and install it to Android device then the new one app substitute (delete the old one) the old one installed earlier.
When I develop native app in Android Studio I have no such an issue.

I searched Ionic [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/) but this issue is not found.
I have only suggestions that the issue will resolve after building with some flag (ex. --release) or signing the app's apk-file.

**The ISSUE** was the "android" folder had existed already. So I described the solution in the answer.
This issue appear only if the app ID is not changed before the first android/ios adding.

**Search for "com."** across the project

```
12 results - 6 files

android/build.gradle:
       9      dependencies {
      10:         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'
      11:         classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
      12  

android/app/build.gradle:

       1: apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
       2  

      46      if (servicesJSON.text) {
      47:         apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
      48      }

android/app/src/androidTest/java/com/getcapacitor/myapp/ExampleInstrumentedTest.java:

       1: package com.getcapacitor.myapp;
       2  
    
      23  
      24:         assertEquals("com.getcapacitor.app", appContext.getPackageName());
      25      }

android/app/src/main/assets/capacitor.plugins.json:
  

     3          "pkg": "@capacitor/app",
       4:       "classpath": "com.capacitorjs.plugins.app.AppPlugin"
       5    },
    
       7        "pkg": "@capacitor/haptics",
       8:       "classpath": "com.capacitorjs.plugins.haptics.HapticsPlugin"
       9    },
    
      11        "pkg": "@capacitor/keyboard",
      12:       "classpath": "com.capacitorjs.plugins.keyboard.KeyboardPlugin"
      13    },
    
      15        "pkg": "@capacitor/status-bar",
      16:       "classpath": "com.capacitorjs.plugins.statusbar.StatusBarPlugin"
      17    }

android/app/src/main/java/io/ionic/starter/MainActivity.java:

      2  
      3: import com.getcapacitor.BridgeActivity;
      4  

android/app/src/test/java/com/getcapacitor/myapp/ExampleUnitTest.java:

      1: package com.getcapacitor.myapp;
      2
```

Comment: if you are using Capacitor you must change your package id in `capacitor.config.ts` or if your are using cordova you must change condifg.xml. both files will be in root directory of your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!

1. Delete "android' folder
2. Change the appId to: 'io.ionic.yourApp' in capacitor.config.ts
3. cmd `ionic cap add android` (I rebuilt "www" folder too before this) That's all.

Answer (score 0):

You must change the package name in the config.xml. because the new one have the same package name of the other apps .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: There is no config.xml file

Answer (score 0):

Your app probably has a package named 'com.example.app' in config.xml, so you have to change to something along those lines, like 'com.dziamid.thatawesomeapp', then your next app will have a package 'com.dziamid.evenmoreawesomeapp' etc. If you're on capacitor, check capacitor.config.json too, for appId and appName.

Comment: There is no config.xml file

Comment: Have you tried searching for 'com.example.app' in your project? The search result might point you to the file/value you need to change. If that search fails, search for 'com.' (with a dot) and look for a generic package name.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. Could you, please, point out what is the exact place where to change the package ID? I edited the question with the code search results.

Comment: OK, I solved it